# why is y[0] different from digits[0] in this code converting integers to a string?

Tags: python

Given the code below, can anyone explain to me what's different between `y[0]` and `digits[0]`?

```
import random
digits = list(range(10)) 
random.shuffle(digits) 
y = str(digits[:3]) 
print (y[0])
print (digits[0])
```

Comment: You are not converting an int to the string but part of the list. So `y` is something like `[7, 2, 6]`

Answer (score 3):

`digits` is a list. The `0th` index of a `list` will return the first item. E.g.

```
digits = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(digits[0])
# 0
```

`y` is a *string representation* of a part of the `digits` list (that's what `[:3]` does, it returns a slice of the list, up to but not including the 4th item). Indexing the `0th` element of a string will return the first character of the string, or `'['`.

```
y = str(digits[:3])
print(y)
# '[0, 1, 2]'
print(y[0])
# '['
```

The reason that the indexing works on both the `list` type and the `str` type is that they are both sequences. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str).